# Should the phone be fully charged before flashing a rom?

Tags: battery, rom-flashing

In [posts like this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1008511), and from other sources, I have heard that the handset should be fully charged before flashing or installing a customer ROM.  I assume this is because the calibration for the battery is kept somewhere within the ROM, but I don't know for sure.  Is this really necessary?

Comment: For most ROMs if you are over 50% battery you'll be alright

Comment: I always just leave my phone plugged in while I make backups or flash a new ROM.  If you're concerned with battery calibration you can manually reset it by fully charging your phone and then letting it run down to the point where it shuts itself off twice in a row with no charging between 100% and 0%.

Comment: @JonnyP Thanks, I'm definitely familiar with the calibration reset method, but I am more concerned with whether or not it is even necessary.  Seems like this is more a measure to prevent borking the rom than anything else.

Comment: That's my feeling as well.  Better safe than sorry when the consequences are so drastic.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's just because, under some circumstances, flashing can take a while.  You **really** don't want your device shutting off while it's being flashed; it can brick the device.

The calibration for the battery is stored, yes, but usually it gets adjusted within a few charges of the phone.  It might be a little inaccurate for a while, but it's not a major concern.